# Need better Node.js http.get request error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use following `http.get()` call to call a local endpoint:

```
http.get({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 80,
    path: '/service/info?id=' + id
}, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    var data = "";

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        if(data.length > 0) {
            try {
                var data_object = JSON.parse(data);
            } catch(e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}).on("error", function (){console.log("GET request error")});
```

However, if I send a malformed request, which would trigger a HTTP 400, the request is synthetically incorrect etc, even though the `response.statusCode` in `function(response)` is 400, it would end up to the `catch() response.on('end', function() {}` instead of emitting the error event on `http.get()`, I wonder why that's the case and how i can handle HTTP 400 response as an error on node.js.

If it gets to `catch(e)`, it waits a long time till it responses anything to the client, which is also weird. I want the server to respond to the client that it hits a 400 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

response.statusCode contains the status code, you can get that in the http.get(...,cb()) or you can set up a listener

```
    request.on('response', function (response) {});
```

that can get the status code.  You can then destroy the request if you want to cancel the GET, or handle it however you want.

Comment: i see, i will try that event

Answer (score 14):

Elaborating on jeremy's answer, here is an example of checking the status code that works for me:

```
  http.get(url, function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode != 200) {
      console.log("non-200 response status code:", res.statusCode);
      console.log("for url:", url);
      return;
    }
    // do something great :-)

  });
```